# Does the RTX2070 graphics card not support DirectX 12 Feature Level 12_2?

Tags: directx-12, rtx

My project uses shader model 6.6 that released by MS recently, but when I move the project from PC that have 3060 graphics card to 2070 super, debug layer says:

Unrecognized D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL (0xc200) for MinimumFeatureLevel. [ INITIALIZATION ERROR #506: CREATEDEVICE_INVALIDARGS]

Just like this...
I've updated my windows version and graphics driver, but it doesn't help anything.

dxdiag says it doesn't support 12_2, but Nvidia homepage says it supports DirectX12 Ultamate(AKA Feature Level 12_2)

is there any way to use 12_2 features in my computer?

Comment: This question is not really about programming. Anyhow, cite your sources.  This doesn't list the card https://www.nvidia.com/nl-nl/geforce/technologies/directx-12-ultimate/

Comment: Note you can use a number of DirectX 12 Ultimate features without having Feature Level 12.2 by checking for the individual optional features via ``CheckFeatureSupport``. The driver/video card has to support *all* features to report 12.2. You may also need to install a newer driver from NVIDIA instead of using the one on Windows Update.